# Evenly distributed differences between their positions

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` `test`

```
test=data.table(x=c(1,2,NA,NA,5))
test
    x
1:  1
2:  2
3: NA
4: NA
5:  5
```

and I want to get

```
test
    x y
1:  1 1
2:  2 1
3: NA 1
4: NA 1
5:  5 NA
```

like 5-2=3 and equally distributed to 3 row

`diff()` function only work for

```
data.table(x,y=c(diff(x),NA))
    x  y
1:  1  1
2:  2 NA
3: NA NA
4: NA NA
5:  5 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized but somewhat over complicated solution (IMO) that seem to work for all the case I've tested

```
test[, y := {
  indx <- !is.na(x)
  indx2 <- .I[indx]
  c(rep(NA, min(indx2) - 1), 
    rep(diff(x[indx]) / diff(indx2), diff(indx2)), 
    rep(NA, .N - max(indx2) + 1))
}]

test
#     x  y
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  2  1
# 3: NA  1
# 4: NA  1
# 5:  5 NA
```

This is basically divides the non-NA values differences by the differences of their positions and then replicates them. It also adds `NA` from right and left in case the values at the beginning or at the end are `NA`.